# View Keychain from encrypted IOS 8.2 backup?

Tags: iphone, backup, keychain

Is there any way to access the keychain from an Iphone 5 IOS 8.2 backup?

Here are the hard facts:

- encrypted backup where I KNOW the password
- device is lost

So far I could restore all the (important) files just fine, however I am stuck on how to view my saved passwords. Apple support sites only show me how to restore a backup, but not how to read it. After searching for quite some time
I found two possibilities:

1. [Decrypting the iPhone keychain from backups](http://www.securitylearn.net/2012/05/03/decrypting-the-iphone-keychain-from-backups/)

This requires me to have not only any iPhone (like the Apple support pages) but even the original one, which I have the backup of. So that's not possible.

2. [Elcomsoft Phone Breaker](https://www.elcomsoft.com/eppb.html)

This seems to work. I downloaded the demo version, which shows which passwords are saved on the backups, but not what they are. However, the cheapest version for OS X is 199€.

Isn't there any other way to access my data for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and found a great article that helped me decrypt the keychain from my iOS 9 backup: [Recovering Google Authenticator Keys from iOS Backups](https://dpron.com/recovering-google-authenticator-keys-from-ios-backups/).

Here are the steps for El Capitan:

- Install pip: `sudo easy_install pip`
- Install m2crypto (see answer to [Trouble installing m2crypto with pip on El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33125400/3790806))

  - First, install openssl and swig with Homebrew: `brew install openssl swig`
  - Then install m2crypto using pip:

    ```
    env LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" \
    CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" \
    SWIG_FEATURES="-cpperraswarn -includeall -I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" \
    pip install --user m2crypto
    ```
- Install some more Python packages:

  ```
  pip install --user construct progressbar pycrypto pyasn1
  ```
- Download the [iPhone Data Protection Tools](https://github.com/dinosec/iphone-dataprotection)
- Extract your backup: `python backup_tool.py PATH_TO_BACKUP`
- And finally, decrypt your keychain:

  ```
  python keychain_tool.py -d "PATH_TO_extract/KeychainDomain/keychain-backup.plist" "PATH_TO_extract/Manifest.plist"
  ```

Answer (score -2):

Try this tutorial - how to decrypt keychain

http://www.securitylearn.net/2012/05/03/decrypting-the-iphone-keychain-from-backups/

Comment: Hi Bleeder, user1068464 already mentioned this in his answer and link only answers are not welcome either. [Take a look here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)